# how to display the image in galleryview

Tags: android

I create gallery view in my application. it is working fine but i want which image focused in the gallery that image also display on the screen at the same time. can anyone help for this

Regards
Raj.

Comment: http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/05/gallery-view-android-developer-tutorial.html checkout this.

Comment: not like that because that example explain the after clicking the any image then only image will be display. but i am calling this method gallery.setSelection(1); in this method in my galleryview method now first image is focused in the galleryview. exactly what i need is that focused image with display the image on the screen. can anyone help me for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the gallery's setOnItemSelectedListener to do action on item focus see [example](http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/07/android-gallery-control.html)

Comment: not like that because that example explain the after clicking the any image then only image will be display. but i am calling this method gallery.setSelection(1); in this method in my galleryview method now first image is focused in the galleryview. exactly what i need is that focused image with display the image on the screen. can anyone help me for this

Comment: in Example, had you scroll the gallery, without using the button(previous or next)?